# Wordpress 3.0 PHP Error - notice WordPress_product_Type was called incorrectly

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, errors

I recently updated WP and some plugins and now I get this on all of my related product tabs. I know it says "Try: $product->get_type();" but I'm confused on where I should replace the old version with this version. It seems to be using "$product->product_type;" and says that it shouldn't be called directly.

I'm lost on this one.

Comment: It should say what file and line that error is on.

Comment: And if its coming from a plugin, you should let the plugin author know.

Comment: Sorry, it's on line 4137 of wp-includes/function.php, which just shows the trigger message. But nothing else or any explicit error

Comment: I see, do you have any custom Woo templates in your theme that need to be updated?